# How to convert single element to arraylist and format to json using jersey?

Tags: java, json, arraylist, jersey

Jersey by default convert single element returned to object . But the client side is expecting the data in json to be arraylist

Model class is LocationDetails

```
public class LocationDetails {
    private String locationAccount;
    private String locationName;
    private String locationStreet;
    private String locationPostcode;
}
```

other class LocationData which has arraylist of LocationDetails as

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class LocationData {
    private ArrayList<LocationDetails> Locations;
}
```

and the controller class is using the following code to convert to JSON:

```
  //Getting location and item along with barcodes
        @POST
        @Path("/getLocationAndItemData")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public LocationResponse getAlllocations(){
               ArrayList<LocationDetails> locationDetailList = new ArrayList<LocationDetails>();
               LocationDetails details = new LocationDetails();
           //setting location account                        
               details.setLocationAccount("10125");
               locationDetailList.add(details); 
}
```

The following code is returning json as `LocationData : {LocationDetails : {"LocationAccount","10125"}}`

whereas i want it to be like :

```
LocationData : {LocationDetails : [{"LocationAccount","10125"}]}
```

as the client side would expect the data to be inside list.

How to convert the type without changing the whole logic.I am using jersey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation to your `List`, that should do the trick. If you have further problems with Jersey, try first XML output to see what is being produced. If XML is ok, JSON will be too.

```
@XmlElement(name="locationDetail")
@XmlElementWrapper(name="locationDetails")
private List<LocationDetail> locationDetails;
```

Also name your class properties with first lowercase letter, please.

Comment: Just add the annotations in `LocationData` class above `private List<LocationDetail> locations` statement. Check Jersey documentation how to handle Lists.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue, after so many research i found that the problem is due to the jar files imported in the `MyEclipse` (Persisted container). I have removed that. The same code works for me.
The `json` format will be `[{single element}].`